# Position div to make it visible while scroll

Tags: jquery, css

If I have a **div** with an overflow property and a wide (many columns) table within that **div** how would I position another element inside the first container that will remain  visible withing the **div** as I scroll to the right/left while I view table data?

```
<div id="mainContainer" style="width:300px; overflow-x:auto">
    <div id="floatingContainer" style="border: 1px solid #ccc">Stay in the middle</div>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Can it be done with CSS only or do I need to add some jQuery? I guess it's something like position: fixed except relative to the div that I place it in...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/eeRMV/7/

I didnt get it to work without the use of specific height attributes.

But some1 with more experience probably knows a way to do this without adding a specific height attr. to the three elements (#mainContainer,#floatingContainer,table).

Comment: your fixed content is fixed relative to the window, not relatively to the parent element. If someone scrolls horizontally on the page it will look very weird.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to add "position:relative;" to the parent element. I think this should work now: http://jsfiddle.net/eeRMV/7/

Comment: p.s. I have also changed the link in my answer to the new link. Thanks @ Olivieradam666 !

Comment: Actually I don't think you can declare a position:fixed relative to something else than the window. In any case your fix does not work, see http://jsfiddle.net/eeRMV/13/ (just added a zero to your mainContainer height attribute)

Comment: You are right again :) I guess it cant be done using css only -at least I cant :/ Thanks for your insights! @op: go with the jquery way if nobody else finds a css-only way.

Answer (score 0):

Put your table in a div for whom who set width and height and with css property overflow: auto. That should give you the expected result

```
<div id="mainContainer" style="width:300px; overflow-x:auto">
<div id="floatingContainer" style="border: 1px solid #ccc">Stay in the middle</div>
<div style"height:100px;overflow: auto">   
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

EDIT: If you want a scrollbar on your whole container you can go the jQuery way.

```
var floatingContainer = $('#floatingContainer');
$('#mainContainer').scroll(function(event) {
    floatingContainer.css('margin-left', event.currentTarget.scrollLeft);
});
```

Here is a [demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eeRMV/14/).

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that will make my life easier, without overcomplicating the issue.